# TableView and Custom Cells

Tags: iphone, tableview, cells

I am in a need for someone to help me out on switching custom cells when selected using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, so the idea is to have custom `cell1` set as a state and when the user selects it this will disappear and `cell2` will fade in which shows the capital of that state but other cells will remain as cell1 (or states) except the one which was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it...

tableView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface tableView : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *tableArray;
}

- (void)changeTitleAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end
```

tableview.m (add these methods) :

in -(void)viewDidLoad add:

```
    tableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tableArray addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],@"City1",@"Capital1",nil]];
    [tableArray addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],@"City2",@"Capital2",nil]];
    [tableArray addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],@"City3",@"Capital3",nil]];
    [tableArray addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],@"City4",@"Capital4",nil]];
```

change:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if (![[[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0] boolValue]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1];
    }else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:2]; 
    }




    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self changeTitleAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}
```

add:

```
- (void)changeTitleAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    BOOL newBool = ![[[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0] boolValue];
    [[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:newBool]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use only one cell, with multiples views (some views with alpha set to transparent, or hide)

when the cell is selected, switch the views inside an animation block